# Navigation Properties become null after using clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a Database Entity Model within my ASP.Net Project

[image: Model.edmx construct]

There are two foreignkeyconstructs, both are constructs between the id's in the shown relation.

Now I'm trying to add 100 sample entries with the following method

```
            IntraNetEntities entities = new IntraNetEntities();

        if (entities.EmployeeList.Count() == 0)
        {
            using (entities)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {     

                    EmployeeList newEmployeeList = new EmployeeList()
                    {
                        department = "Standardabteilung",
                        mobile = i,
                        landline = 1 + i,
                        mail = "Standardemail",
                        position = "Standardfunktion",
                        shortcode = "abc",
                        lastname = "StandardNachname",
                        roomnumber = Convert.ToDouble(i),
                        firstname = "Standardvorname"
                    };

                    PrivateContact newPrivateContact = new PrivateContact()
                    {
                            city = "Standardstadt",
                            country = "deutscheland",
                            landline = i,
                            mail = "standardemail",
                            mobile = i * 2,
                            street = "standardstreet",
                            zip = i * 10,
                            EmployeeList = newEmployeeList
                    };

                    WorkContact newWorkContact = new WorkContact()
                    {
                        city = "Standardstadt",
                        country = "deutscheland",
                        landline = i * 9,
                        mobile = i * 12 / 8,
                        mail = "standardmail",
                        street = "standardstraße",
                        zip = i * 9,
                        EmployeeList = newEmployeeList
                    };

                    newEmployeeList.PrivateContact = newPrivateContact;
                    newEmployeeList.WorkContact = newWorkContact;

                    entities.AddToEmployeeList(newEmployeeList);
                    entities.AddToPrivateContact(newPrivateContact);
                    entities.AddToWorkContact(newWorkContact);

                }

                entities.saveChanges();

                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

My problem is, that my Navigation Properties disappear when this method ends! 
They all look fine in debugging while still being in the using case but afterwards they are all null without me doing any changes to those values.

How can I keep the navigation values?

Thanks

Comment: Just so I am clear - do you mean that the new contacts and employee lists aren't being persisted to the database? Or that newPrivateContact.EmployeeList is losing its value and becoming null (and if this is what you mean, how are you accessing newPrivateContact outside the using given that its scope is within the using itself)? Or something else?

Comment: I just wanted to keep the Navigation Properties. I mean that newPrivateContact.EmployeeList and/or newEmployeeList.PrivateContact are losing their value! Given that newEmployeeList and newPrivateContact are both Elements called and selected in a new using clause after this using clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using calls "Dispose" at the end of it. That's why your navigation properties drop off. From the MSDN website:

> The using statement calls the Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is called.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

> The using statement allows the programmer to specify when objects that use resources should release them.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: So is there any way to save the Context, those Navigation Properties?

Comment: Well, if you are choosing to put it in a Using statement, then you are explicitly telling the program to NOT save that context once the using scope is finished. Technically, you don't always need the Using statement, so you can experiment with removing altogether. I've passed a Context obj around a small-ish application as a ref parameter to various library functions, and this works fine (although it might not scale well).

Answer (score 0):

When exiting the `using` block, your context will get disposed.
Navigation properties needs an exisiting context. So you have to ensure that your context object lives long enough.

You might consider using [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/AspNetIntegration) or another di framework which has support for asp.net.

With using the `HttpRequestScoped()` extension method your context will get constructed and disposed according to the livecycle of the web request:

```
builder.RegisterType<IntraNetEntities>().As<IntraNetEntities>().HttpRequestScoped();
```